# How to put video default language when you update?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using youtube api v3 for updating video parameters:

> ```
> var resource = {
>  id: videoId,
>  snippet: {
>    title: "my title",
>    description: "my description",
>    tags: tagsArray,
>    categoryId: '22',    
>  },
>    YouTube.Videos.update(resource, 'id,snippet');
> ```

But when I use these code the default language puts English in order to use my default channel language Spanish. I would like to put Spanish like language. How can I put the language in the youtube video with google youtube api v3?

I don't see anything in the oficial documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update?hl=es

[image]

Comment: Just a thought, try search in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) and see if there are any issue reported related to yours. The point is find code that might help you - since there it is required to put the code of the issue.